# Activity won't start even though it's declared in manifest file

Tags: android

I have an activity which wont start.

The error receive is:

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.its_time/com.example.its_time.actiongenre.ActioncomedyActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I have checked, and the activity is declared in the manifest file.

Why do I still get this error eventhough its declared ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.its_time"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".mainmenu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".mainmenu.NextactivityActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nextactivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".mainmenu.Next100moviesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_next100movies" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".mainmenu.NextTvSeriesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_next_tv_series" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".top100list.Top100listActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_top100list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".top100list.ThegodfatherActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_thegodfather" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".moviegenres.ActiongenreActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_actiongenre" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".moviegenres.ComedyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_comedy" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".moviegenres.ScifiActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scifi" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".moviegenres.AnimationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_animation" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".moviegenres.DokumentaryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dokumentary" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".moviegenres.HorrorActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_horror" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".actiongenre.ScifiActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scifi" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".moviegenres.Drama2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drama2" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".actiongenre.ActioncomedyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_actioncomedy" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".actiongenre.AdventureActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_adventure" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".actiongenre.WesternActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_western" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".actiongenre.ActiondramaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_actiondrama" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".actiongenre.ActionthrillerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_actionthriller" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".actiongenre.ActionfantaasyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_actionfantaasy" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".animationgenres.AnimationActionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_animation_action" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".animationgenres.AnimadventureActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_animadventure" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".animationgenres.AnimcomedyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_animcomedy" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".animationgenres.AnimdramaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_animdrama" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="comedygenres.ComedyromanceActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_comedyromance" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ancomedygenres.ComedydramaActivityramaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_comedydrama" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="comedygenres.ComedyactionActivitye.ComedyactionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_comedyaction" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="comedygenres.ComedycomedyActivitye.ComedycomedyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_comedycomedy" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".documentarysubgenres.DocumentaryWarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_documentary_war" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".documentarysubgenres.DocumentaryBiografiActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_documentary_biografi" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DocumentaryMusikActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_documentary_musik" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DocumentarySportActivity"
            android:label="andcom.example.its_time.documentarysubgenres.DocumentaryNatureActivityactivity_documentary_sport" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Doccom.example.its_time.documentarysubgenres.DocumentaryHistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_documentary_nature" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DocumentaryHistoryActivity"
            android:label="androcom.example.its_time.documentarysubgenres.DocumentaryDramaActivityctivity_documentary_history" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DocumentaryDramaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_documentary_drama" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".documentarysubgenres.DocumentaryCultureAndPoliticsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_documentary_culture_and_politics" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DocumentaryBrottActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_documentary_brott" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".horrorsubgenres.HorrorThrillerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_horror_thriller" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HorrorHorrorActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_horror_horror" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".horrorsubgenres.HorrorScifiActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_horror_scifi" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ScifiDramaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scifi_drama" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ScifiThrillerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scifi_thriller" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ScifiAdventureActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scifi_adventure" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ScifiActionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scifi_action" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ScifiHorrorActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scifi_horror" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DramaSportActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drama_sport" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DramaComedyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drama_comedy" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DramaAdventureActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drama_adventure" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DramaActionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drama_action" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DramaDramaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drama_drama" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DramaRomantikActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drama_romantik" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DramaThrillerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drama_thriller" > 
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nextactivity);

        pupulateListView();
        registerClickCallback();
    }

    private void registerClickCallback() {
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewGenres);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent;
                switch(position)
                {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(NextactivityActivity.this,ActiongenreActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(NextactivityActivity.this,AnimationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(NextactivityActivity.this,ComedyActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent = new Intent(NextactivityActivity.this,DokumentaryActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    intent = new Intent(NextactivityActivity.this,HorrorActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    intent = new Intent(NextactivityActivity.this,ScifiActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    intent = new Intent(NextactivityActivity.this,Drama2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void pupulateListView() {
        String[] myItems = {"Action","Animation","Komedi","Dokumentär","Skräck","Sci-fi","Drama"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.the_list_genres,myItems);
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewGenres);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    }
```

This is the first piece of code that takes me to the next step, this process works

This is the next steps code, which will take me to the third step:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actiongenre);

        populateListView();
        registerClickCallback();

    }

    private void registerClickCallback() {

ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewActionSubgenres);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent;
                switch(position)
                {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(ActiongenreActivity.this,Actioncomedyactivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(ActiongenreActivity.this,Actionadventureactivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(ActiongenreActivity.this,ActionWesternActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent = new Intent(ActiongenreActivity.this,ActiondramaActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    intent = new Intent(ActiongenreActivity.this,ActionthrillerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    intent = new Intent(ActiongenreActivity.this,ActionfantaasyActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

            }
        });



    }
    private void populateListView() {
        String[] myItems = {"Komedi","Äventyr","Western","Drama","Thriller","Fantasi"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.the_list,myItems);
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewActionSubgenres);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

But its this third step which doesnt work, and as you can see the code for the first
process is almost identical to the second

Comment: post your manifest file.

Comment: Looks like you have it declared or subpackaged weird

Comment: Check your activity name with declared activity name in manifest

Comment: Do all the others work?

Comment: A long shot but have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: Yes, didn't change anything

Comment: OK, post the code you're using to try to start the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has `Actioncomedyactivity` while the manifest has `ActioncomedyActivity`. The `a` vs. `A` matters.

Comment: I picked up on that too but the weird thing is the error is saying it can't find "ActioncomedyActivity" (with capital 'A' for Activity). Why would it say that if the `Intent` is attempting to explicitly start `Actioncomedyactivity.class`? Something isn't right with the manifest and/or code the OP has posted but I agree with your answer.

Comment: Yes, the error message doesn't match the code exactly. Possibly it's from a different version of the app, or copying the error here introduced some changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this

```
  android:name=".actiongenre.ActioncomedyActivity"
```

with your complete package name enclosing ActionComedyActivity like this

```
  android:name="youCompletePackageName.Actioncomedyactivity"
```

Comment: can you have the screenshot of the file explorer in Eclipse with the corresponding package name and Activity expanded??

Comment: Cant do that, need 10 in reputation to post image